# Pandas не показывает больше 100 столбцов при автозавершении

Tags: python, pandas

pandas >=0.23.0 не отображается столбцы 101+.[image: pandas 0.23.0]

pandas 0.22.0  и младше  - все работает норм.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `pd.options.display.max_rows`  что говорит? Если 100, то поставьте сколько вам нужно. И зачем вы привели скриншоты, если из них все равно кроме версий ничего не понятно?

Comment: это совершенно не та опция, вывод датафрейма тут не при чем. Проблема в том что когда набираю df.название_столбца через таб не все столбцы отображаются

Comment: Тогда вообще не понятно о чем речь. Что вам IDLE или IPython не показывают? все возможные методы для автозаполнения? тогда при чем здесь столбцы?

Comment: при том что должно автозаполнять  и название полей, всех, а не только первых 100

Comment: То есть, речь идет о названиях колонок датафрейма, а не каких-то "полей"? А что говорит ваш IPythton на `jedi.__version__`? В обоих случаях? Вы же понимаете, что `pandas` здесь ни при чём?

Answer (score 0):

Pandas не обещает вам, что доступ к столбцу возможен через поле, поэтому так делать и не стоит.

Обращение к столбцам DataFrame лучше осуществлять через квадратные скобки.
Список всех столбцов можно получить с помощью `df.columns.values.tolist()`
или `sorted(df)`
для поиска нужного столбца можно использовать следующую lambda-функцию

```
find_col = lambda df, substr: [col for col in sorted(df) if substr in col]
```

получающую данные и подстроку-столбца, которую ищите.

Почему важно не обращаться к полям напрямую? Питон не может иметь в названии переменных любые спец символы, кроме "_". А значит встретив столбец с названием "Столбец №1" вы не сможете получить доступ к нему напрямую. Нужно использовать:`df["Столбец №1"]`

Comment: нет, нзвание колонки не отображается, когда набираю df.название_поля  <TAB>

Comment: @DimaKey То есть вы жалуетесь на смену внутреннего строения DataFrame. Не стоит использовать поля объектов напрямую, используйте соответствующие методы.

Comment: @DimaKey несколько вариантов получения названия столбцов представлены в статье https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-column-names-in-pandas-dataframe/

Comment: @DimaKey получить значения определенного столбца можно через квадратные скобки

Comment: а как мне обращаться к полю, запомниать название 600 полей датафрейма? 
просто не понятно почему лимит 100 полей

Comment: @DimaKey добавляю в ответ lambda функцию фильтрующую колонки по подстроке, можно использовать её